# How to connect messenger platform to location subpages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page, facebook-messenger-bot

I have a connected messenger platform to the main page of the facebook.
How to connect messenger platform (bot) to location subpages?
I can not get a access token to child pages for use in an API (Messenger Platform).
Thank you

Comment: That whole child pages stuff isn’t documented very well. Have you actually tried getting a page access token for the child pages? My first guess would be `child-page-id?fields=access_token`, analog to “normal” pages.